# ¿Por qué no me crea mi BD Sqlite al momento de Iniciar la app de Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Lo que quiero es crear una base de datos al momento de que inicie mi aplicación de Android.

Código de SqliteOpenHelper:

```
public class BDSqlite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String SQL_CREAR  = "create table "
            + "Prueba" + "(" + "_id"
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + "Name"
            + " text not null);";


    public BDSqlite(Context context) {
        super(context, "Prueba.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREAR);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Código de mi Actividad:

```
public class CRUD_Sqlite extends AppCompatActivity {
    BDSqlite mHelper;
     SQLiteDatabase mDatenbank;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.crud_sqlite);
        mHelper = new BDSqlite(this);
        mDatenbank = mHelper.getReadableDatabase(); //Datenbank öffnen
    }


    public void crearS(View v) {

    }


}
```

Para probar si creo o no la BD de sqlite fui a la carpeta data que me muestra el android device monitor y en teoría ahí me la debería crear, pero no hay nada.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo hecho un proyecto similar con una BD SQLite y lo he hecho además con un Manager para la BD. No obstante, solamente has dado permisos de lectura de la base de datos:

```
mHelper = new BDSqlite(this);
mDatenbank = mHelper.getReadableDatabase(); //Datenbank öffnen
```

Si quieres escribir datos en la bd deberías darle permisos de escritura:

```
mDatenbank = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Aún así, en mi proyecto tengo una clase DBManager, en cuyo constructor tengo lo siguiente:

```
public DbManager(Context context) {
    helper=new DbHelper(context);
    db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

db es un objeto SQLiteDatabase:

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;
```

Queda claro también que helper es un objeto de la clase DbHelper que extiende de SQLiteOpenHelper.

```
private DbHelper helper;
```

En esta clase tengo todas las sentencias para acceso y modificación de los datos de la BD.